# How to "skip" submodule declaration on import

Tags: python, django

Starting with the structure (this is a Django project).

```
root/
    app_1/
        views.py
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        submodule/
            __init__.py
            mixins.py
```

I can normally import on `app_1/views.py` with the full declaration.

```py
from my_module.submodule.mixins import MyMixin
```

But I wish to skip declaring `submodule`.

```py
from my_module.mixins import MyMixin
```

I've tried some combinations of `from x import y` on both `__init__.py` files in `my_module` and `sub_module` but I've only managed to skip the submodules altogether.

```py
from my_module import MyMixin
```

I don't love this option because it hides all my files.

Is there a way to get it the way I want?

Comment: You cannot write `from my_module.mixins import MyMixin` because there is no module `mixins` in `my_module` (even if you import it inside `__init__` it is not a module). If you really want this you can add a file `mixins.py` inside `my_module` inside which you write `from .submodule.mixins import MyMixin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by some comments, it is not possible to do exactly as I wanted.

What I ended up doing was to move my files from `submodule` to `my_module`. This mitigated the problem and I managed to do the `import` as I wanted.

```sh
root/
    app_1/
        views.py
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        mixins.py
```

This was possible in my project's structure but might not be an option for everyone, so feel free to use the alternatives mentioned by the other users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `mixins` in the `__init__.py` file inside your `my_module` directory.

`root/my_module/__init__.py`:

```py
from .submodule import mixins
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work... After setting that up, trying to import with `from my_module.mixins import MyMixin`, the module is not found with the error: `ImportError: No module named mixins`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific submodule classes exposed, go with what @abdul-aziz-barkat said. If you want to expose the entire submodule.mixins API, you can do the following file.

`root/my_module/mixins.py`

```
from .submodule.mixins import *
```

Note that you should only do this with a single submodule import. When you start importing multiple submodules with `*`, you can run into problems.